# Вывод datetime из базы MySql на PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Есть база *MySql*. Хранится время в `datetime`

Пример:

```
2015-07-23 11:30:00
```

Как вывести все, что есть в базе Сегодня (сегодняшним числом) и завтра (завтрашним числом)?

Спасибо!

P.S. Вариант `MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW())`, `DAYOFYEAR(NOW())` и `date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)` работают не корректно, выводят от сегодня и все что есть в базе от сегодня.

Comment: А данные от "завтра" в базе есть вообще?

Comment: Есть на пол месяца в перед ))

Comment: "пол месяца" и "в перед" - priceless! "Не гляди на зад, не гляди" (c).

Comment: *выводят от сегодня и все что есть в базе от сегодня* — если это требование попытаться изложить чуть более правильным языком, то оно воспринимается как: «выводит записи за сегодняшний день **и** все записи за сегодняшний день» — т.е. слева и справа от `и` написано, фактически, одно и то же. но вы наверняка подразумевали что-то иное. пожалуйста, попробуйте сформулировать чуть иначе, чтобы ваша мысль стала яснее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо отбросить время:

```
$date = strtotime('today'); // или strtotime('tomorrow')
$result = mysqli_query(
    $link,
    "SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE DATE(`myfield`) = '".date('Y-m-d', $date)."'"
);
```

Совпадение имен может сбить с толку, хотя действие функций разное.
Здесь MySQL функция date() приводит тип к дате без времени. А PHP-шная date() формирует строку по указанному формату. В итоге получаем сравнимые значения :)

Недостаток запроса в том, что MySQL не сумеет применить индекс, т.к. слева от "=" стоит выражение, а не имя поля.
Можно переделать на `… WHERE myfield >= '{$d}' AND myfield < '{$d}' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`
где $d = date('Y-m-d', $date)

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!

Answer (score 1):

например, так (первый запрос — все строки, второй — только за сегодня и завтра):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59925/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (date datetime);

insert into t values
  (now()),
  (now() + interval 1 day),
  (now() + interval 2 day),
  (now() - interval 1 day),
  (now() - interval 2 day),
  (now() - interval 3 day);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from t order by date
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59925/2/0)**:

```
|                   date |
|------------------------|
| July, 20 2015 15:51:56 |
| July, 21 2015 15:51:56 |
| July, 22 2015 15:51:56 |
| July, 23 2015 15:51:56 |
| July, 24 2015 15:51:56 |
| July, 25 2015 15:51:56 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select * from t
where date between curdate()
  and curdate() + interval 2 day
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59925/2/1)**:

```
|                   date |
|------------------------|
| July, 23 2015 15:51:56 |
| July, 24 2015 15:51:56 |
```

Comment: У Вас в примере выводит м 23 и 24 число. Нужно за сегодня одно число, к примеру 23, за завтра 24. Я так пробовал, не то.

Comment: я, видимо, совсем вас не понял. вы и описываете то, что у меня во втором запросе. возможно, если вы переформулируете, или пример приведёте, что именно вам нужно, мы лучше поймём друг друга.

Comment: `… curdate() + interval 2 day` — а почему *2* ?

Comment: @artoodetoo, `curdate()` возвращает дату, а после её преобразования в, например, `datetime`, это будет момент начала дня (ноль часов ноль минут), т.е. чтобы «захватить» два дня, нужно два дня и прибавить: от нуля часов сегодня до нуля часов **после**-завтра — т.е., войдут все записи за сегодняшний и завтрашний день.